# Bandwidth Speed Test Slower Than Expected

Tags: dart

Im trying to create a bandwidth test using Dart using a LibreSpeed server, but for some reason it's reporting a much slower speed than expected. When I test using the web client for LibreSpeed I get around 30mb/s download bandwidth, however with my Dart program I'm only getting around 4mb/s.

The code for the speed test is as follows:

```dart
Future<void> start() async {
  var rand = Random();
  var req = await client.getUrl(Uri.http(_serverAddress, '/garbage.php',
      {'r': rand.nextDouble().toString(), 'ckSize': '20'}));
  var resp = await req.close();
  var bytesDownloaded = 0;
  var start = DateTime.now();
  await for (var bytes in resp) {
    bytesDownloaded += bytes.length;
  }
  var timeTaken = DateTime.now().difference(start).inSeconds;
  var mbsDownloaded = bytesDownloaded / 1000000;
  print(
      '$mbsDownloaded megabytes downloaded in $timeTaken seconds at a rate of ${mbsDownloaded / timeTaken} mbs per second');
}
```

I think I'm probably not understanding a crucial reason as to why it appears to be so slow compared to the web client. Can anyone give me any ideas as to what the bottleneck might be?

Comment: I think your main problem is a confusion about units in your calculation. E.g. you are aware that what you are calculating is in megabytes per second and not megabits per second? E.g. if I takes your output and multiply with 8 (to get megabits) I can see your program are downloading with 96 Mbit/s on a 100 Mbit/s connection which I think is acceptable. In your example it would be `4 * 8 = 32 Mbit/s`.

Comment: @julemand101 unfortunately I do want to measure megabytes rather than megabits :/

Comment: That is fine as long your then understand the result. Your code works fine and performance is good at least when tested with a 100 Mbit/s internet connection. Also, the performance numbers fits your internet connection if we converts your numbers. So again, I am just thinking your problem really is a misunderstanding in what internet speed you have yourself (internet providers are often using Mbit/s).

Comment: Or are you saying you have an internet connection which makes it possible to download 30 megabytes per second which means you have a 240 Mbit connection? (The LibreSpeed page are showing the result in Mbps = Mbit/s).

Comment: On closer inspection, you're definitely right actually! Apologies. I didn't read the gauges very carefully. One thing I'm not sure about though is why most people seem to implement speed tests for Flutter using platform channels. Maybe It's to optimise the result? I don't know. Strange that there isn't a simple package written in pure Dart for speed testing on pubdev.

Comment: Dart does have some kind of overhead when downloading stuff since it is allocating a new `List<int>` object for each iteration. This overhead is really not a problem for most internet connections and devices but I would guess it could make a difference if you have an slow device and try tests a gigabit connection.

Comment: About packages, I have the position that too many packages are being created with a very limited purpose and very low quality. Not every functionality needs a package (it is in fact limited how many internet speed test apps we need that uses the same internal shared implementation). :)

Comment: Probably true. I guess the voting system filters out low quality ones though. Yeh sometimes it's better to just go ahead and make your own. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is confusion between the use of units when measure internet speed. In general terms there are two ways we can measure the speed:

- Mbps (MegaBit Per Second)
- MB/s (MegaByte per second)

To understand your problem we need to notice that `1 byte = 8 bits`. Also, that the unit LibreSpeed (and most internet providers) uses is `Mbps`.

The unit your current program are measuring in is `MB/s` since you are using the length of the list (each element of the list is `1 byte = 8 bit`:

```
  await for (var bytes in resp) {
    bytesDownloaded += bytes.length;
  }
```

And never multiply that number by 8 later in your code. You are then comparing this number against the number from LibreSpeed which uses `Mbps` (same as most internet providers) which means your number is 8 times smaller that expected.